# DVD drive connected wirelessly to iPad

Tags: ipad, video, streaming, dvd, movie

I watch a bunch of movies on DVD that I get from Netflix.  I'd really like to watch them from my iPad, but of course my iPad doesn't have a DVD drive.

Is there a way to have a DVD drive somewhere in my house, that can be connected wirelessly to my iPad?  In other words, some way to put the movie DVD into a separate DVD drive, start it playing, and have it beam the movie to my iPad, so I can watch it on my iPad?  Basically, read the movie from my DVD player and then stream it wirelessly to my iPad.  (I don't want something that would require my iPad to be connected via a wire to something else; that would leave me tethered, which is annoying.)

I know I could probably have a separate computer with a DVD drive and manually rip the movie and then somehow transfer it to my iPad, but that's a pain.  I'd prefer something more convenient: just put it into the player, press play, and watch on my iPad.  Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Only if you have a DVD standalone drive with network (WiFi) capability. Do you ?

Comment: Thanks, @Buscar웃!  I'm happy to buy equipment to make this work -- so that sounds like a good solution.  I didn't even know such things exist.  Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

That is possible if:

You have a [DVD drive with WiFi capability](http://www.cnet.com/products/samsung-optical-smart-hub-se-208bw/).

You could connect the DVD drive to your router and access it from your iPad.

Comment: Something like http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/samsung-wi-fi-external-dvd-rw-writer-usb-optical-drive-a51lf for instance?

Answer (score 2):

You can **use VLC to create a network stream**, then open this network stream in the VLC app on your iPad.

For more information, see:

- https://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch02.html

Besides VLC you can use for example [AirVideo](http://www.inmethod.com/index.html), [Plex](https://plex.tv) or [Infuse](http://firecore.com/infuse).